# Can't access master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, master-pages

I am trying to access a repeater in master page from a child page and keep getting null returned for Master. Tried different things on both master page and child page and nothing is working and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

On master page, I have:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="EA.SiteMaster" %>
```

somewhere in master page:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFavorites" OnItemDataBound="rptFavorites_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFavLink" />
            </span> 
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in default.aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="EA.SiteMaster" virtualpath="../Site.master" %>
```

in default.aspx.cs:

```
private void UpdateMaster()
{
    Repeater rptFavorites;
    rptFavorites = (Repeater)this.Master.FindControl("rptFavorites");

    if (rptFavorites != null)
    {
        DataTable dtFavorites = Favorites.GetFavoritesByUserID(Session["UserID"].ToString());
        rptFavorites.DataSource = dtFavorites;
        rptFavorites.DataBind();
    }
}
```

this.Master is always null. I tried keeping the MaterPageFile as MasterType in default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EA._Default" %>
<%@ MasterType TypeName="EA.SiteMaster" virtualpath="../Site.master" %>
```

**Update**

I have a web method in default.aspx.cs, called by a js function in aspx file. Web methods are static so I couldn't just call UpdateMaster() and had to create an instance first, so I did the following (see code below). That's why when it gets to UpdateMaster() it is using a new instance of the page which seems to have no master page. On the other hand, if I don't, I am not sure how to call the function from web method.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AddUserFavorite(string sURL, string sFriendlyName)
{
    string sMsg = string.Empty;
    string sUserID = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    bool bExists = Favorites.FavoriteExists(sUserID, sURL);

    if (bExists)
        sMsg = "This link is already in your favorites list";
    else
    {
        Favorites oFavorite = new Favorites();
        oFavorite.FavoritesURL = sURL;
        oFavorite.FavoritesFriendlyName = sFriendlyName;
        oFavorite.UserID = sUserID;

        int iRet = Favorites.AddFavrites(oFavorite);

        if (-1 == iRet)
            sMsg = "Failed to add to favorites list";
        else
        {
            sMsg = "\"" + sFriendlyName + "\" (" + sURL + ") was added to your favorites list";
            _Default _Def = new _Default();
            _Def.UpdateMaster();
        }
    }
}
        return sMsg;
    }
```

Comment: Is that relative page to your Master page correct? Does `File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../Site.Master"))` return true?

Comment: How do you know `this.Master` is null? Do you get a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: I test through VS and it returns Syste,.NullReferenceException error. When I put a breakpoint, "master" is null.

Comment: I added bool bExists = File.Exists(...) and it returns true.

Comment: one more check if you want: (this would be in default, and assumes Label1 exists): `Label1.Text = MasterPageFile;` to get the virtual path of the master page.

Comment: One more piece of info: I commented out everything and did a Response.Redirect("default.aspx") to refresh the page and master page with it. I got "System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'" Then I added HttpContext.Current before Response and it went through. I am not sure why I need that from default.aspx.cs; it is not a user defined class. I smell fish!

Comment: redirected to itself? or is that redirect on another page?

Comment: to itself; just wanted to refresh the page and refresh master page in the process. I also tried the suggestion of adding a label and setting it to MasterPageFile but when I type Label1. I don't get the context menu and it says Label1 does not exist in this context. It is getting weirder by the minute. There is something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: the top of my content pages looks like this: `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Testing/test-master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testing_default" %>`. that's for a web form. just wondering why yours is so different. is that a web 'page'?

Comment: Same thing except I have codeBehind and you have CodeFile (web project vs web site). I think I know where the problem is but don;t know how to solve. I updated my question. I have a web method that calls UpdateMaster. Because WebMethod is static, I couldn;t just call UpdateMaster and had to create an instance of the page and this is causing the issue.